# Nginx reverse proxy using proxy_pass working for root location, but not subdirectories

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I've been working on this for the better part of a few days and I've been learning how Nginx works as I go, but I'm afraid I've missed something terribly stupid or simple.

I have a webapp running in a docker container at `abc.domainname.com:444`. If I access it at that URL, it's perfectly functional. However, I don't want the port number to be required in the URL so I've been trying to set up Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of that so that if someone accesses `abc.domainname.com` they get all of the content of `abc.domainname.com:444`. After a couple days' work I've been successful in getting the port number out of the URL for direct access, but the docker app is loading a few resources from places like `abc.domainname.com:444/app/dfjsdfksdfjsdkfdsj.js`, `abc.domainname.com:444/images/images1/fjdskds.jpg` and a few other subdirectories within `/app/` and `/images/`. When I access the site at `abc.domainname.com` these assets are not loaded. According to my developer console there's a 404 for each resource. The URL of each resource is correct - or would be if the port number is specified.

Basically, `abc.domainname.com:444/app/dfjsdfksdfjsdkfdsj.js` loads the resource, but with the below Nginx config I've found that it seems like only the root is being proxy passed as that same resource cannot be called as `abc.domainname.com/app/dfjsdfksdfjsdkfdsj.js`

I've even tried to build blocks out for these items to no avail.

I get the feeling that there's an issue with my location blocks that I'm missing. Can anyone with more experience help me figure out my mistake so I can (hopefully) start understanding Nginx location blocks and how Nginx serves as a reverse proxy.

```
server_name             abc.domainname.com;
server_tokens           off;
error_log               /home/runcloud/logs/nginx/Webappy_error.log;
access_log              /home/runcloud/logs/nginx/Webapp_access.log main buffer=16k;
access_log              /var/log/nginx-rc/Webapp_traffic.log traffic buffer=16k;

client_max_body_size    256m;

# Header option for security purpose
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

# HSTS
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;

root /home/runcloud/webapps/Webapp;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    root  /opt/RunCloud/letsencrypt;
}

location / {

    # Proxy config to remove the port number from the URL
    proxy_pass https://abc.domainname.com:444;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~ .(ico|css|gif|jpe?g|png|gz|zip|flv|rar|wmv|avi|css|js|swf|png|htc|mpeg|mpg|txt|otf|ttf|eot|woff|svg)$ {
    expires     1M;
    # Header option for security purpose
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    # HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;

    add_header  Cache-Control "public";
    # Proxy config to remove the port number from the URL
    proxy_pass https://abc.domainname.com:444$request_uri;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;    

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ .(html)$ {
    expires     24h;
    # Header option for security purpose
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    # HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;

    add_header  Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /app/ {
    # Proxy config to remove the port number from the URL
    proxy_pass https://abc.domainname.com:444/app/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location /images/ {
    # Proxy config to remove the port number from the URL
    proxy_pass https://abc.domainname.com:444/images/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri               =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info      ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index                index.php;
    fastcgi_param                SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass                 unix:/var/run/Webapp.sock;
    fastcgi_send_timeout         60;
    fastcgi_read_timeout         60;
    fastcgi_buffer_size          128k;
    fastcgi_buffers              4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout      30s;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```